# Оператор (+) при соединении таблиц по нескольким столбцам

Tags: sql, oracle

Столкнулся со старым оракловым кодом и не вполне понял механику оператора (+). Самый простой случай

```
SELECT *
  FROM A, B
 WHERE A.COL1 = B.COL1(+)
```

Для понимания легко преобразуется в

```
SELECT *
  FROM A
  LEFT JOIN B ON A.COL1 = B.COL1
```

При джойне по нескольким столбцам запрос

```
SELECT *
  FROM A, B
 WHERE A.COL1 = B.COL1(+)
   AND A.COL2 = B.COL2(+)
```

Преобразуется в

```
SELECT *
  FROM A
  LEFT JOIN B ON A.COL1 = B.COL1
             AND A.COL2 = B.COL2
```

А как понимать следующий запрос, когда не все столбцы помечены оператором (+)?

```
SELECT *
  FROM A, B
 WHERE A.COL1 = B.COL1(+)
   AND A.COL2 = B.COL2
```

Будет ли (+) вообще учитываться в данном запросе? В эксперементе с небольшой выборкой у меня выходит, что (+) игнорируется и можно интерпретировать как полностью внутренний джойн. Но его точно нельзя понимать как:

```
SELECT *
  FROM A, B
 WHERE (A.COL1 = B.COL1 OR B.COL1 IS NULL)
   AND A.COL2 = B.COL2
```

Comment: Вроде как `(+)` указывает, к какой таблице идет присоединение. Без указания внешнего соединение происходит `inner` join, если установлен `(+)` в зависимости от столбца, то `right` или `left`. Но это не точно)

Comment: @ipatev_nn ну да, я об этом и говорю в примерах выше. И это действительно так работает, если помечены все столбцы, участвующие в джойне. Вопрос для кейса, когда помечена только часть столбцов. Помеченные столбцы есть, но результат у нас не left и не right.

Comment: так строгое по одному полю, и не строгое по второму, видимо, или что?

Comment: `(+)` означает "либо есть соответствующая запись, либо таковой нет, и следует добавить NULL-запись". Случай, когда только одно условие помечено плюсом, интерпретируется так: "для первого условия либо есть соответствующая запись, либо добавить NULL-запись; для второго условия есть соответствующая запись". Посему "следующий запрос, когда не все столбцы помечены оператором (+)" будет использовать более строгое условие, иначе не все условия отбора будут выполнены (условие для второго поля не допускает добавления NULL-записи), т.е. оно будет работать как INNER JOIN.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Цитата из [документации](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/Joins.html#GUID-29A4584C-0741-4E6A-A89B-DCFAA222994A):

> **Outer Joins**
> [...] or apply the outer join operator (+) **to all columns of B** in the join condition in the WHERE clause.

То есть, в следующем запросе:

```
SELECT *
  FROM A, B
 WHERE A.COL1 = B.COL1(+)
   AND A.COL2 = B.COL2
```

Если не все столбцы помечены оператором (+), следует понимать:

- что это `INNER JOIN`.
- кто-то допустил ошибку забыв убрать лишний оператор (+) из условия соединения.